# Positioning elements around element

Tags: html, css, positioning

I need to position elements on a side like in the image above and have onclick function on them to show the corresponding text. Any info on how to best achieve this to be responsive?
By responseive i mean that the dots and text should always stay on the same position relative to the size of the bottle.

What I did was to put everything inside the container div and then positioned the elements relative to that div and the bottle image absolute to the container div.
It kinda works when container div has fixed dimensions, but I guess there are better ways to do it.

EDIT: Added code! I suck at formatting, sorry.

[image]

```
<div class="bottle-one">
                            <div class="bottle-one-content">
                            <div class="bottle-one-image">
                                <div class="message">
                                    <div class="message-hidden">
                                        <div>
                                            text
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/line_blue.svg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#msg1" class="droplet droplet1 js-drop">
                                        <img src="assets/images/icons/droplet.svg">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message">
                                    <div class="message-hidden">
                                        <div>
                                            text
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/line_blue.svg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#msg2" class="droplet droplet2 js-drop">
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/droplet.svg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message">
                                    <div class="message-hidden">
                                        <div>
                                            text

                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/line_blue.svg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#msg3" class="droplet droplet3 js-drop">
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/droplet.svg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="message">
                                    <div class="message-hidden">
                                        <div>
                                            text
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/line_blue.svg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#msg4" class="droplet droplet4 js-drop">
                                            <img src="assets/images/icons/droplet.svg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <img src="assets/images/bottle1.png" alt="" class="bottle-one-bottle">
                            </div>
                        </div>


    .bottle-one {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 30%;
}

.bottle-one-image {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 251px;
}
.message {
  left: -340px;
  top: 180px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .7rem;
  color: #004197;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.message-hidden {
  display: flex;
}

.message-hidden div:nth-of-type(1)  {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'BrandonGrotesqueWeb-Black', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #004197;
  width: 70%;
}
.message-hidden div:nth-of-type(2)  {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you please put some code you have already written to solve this problem.

Comment: Please read this [ask] and this [mcve]. And to note, SO isn't a code writing service, we help with written code.

Comment: @vjeko, can you please provide more details about what _responsivity_ for this layout do you want? Can you give some examples how should it look at different screen sizes?

Comment: @RamanMishra added the code, sorry about that!

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I just need the dots to stick to the sides and always be in the same position, relative to the size of the bottle

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this to help you with aligning your element to the left of a div.

By using a mix of  `[psuedo-elements]` and `floats`, I think this gives you the desired effect you are looking for. Post your code and I'll be more then happy to help you with the other part.

```css
html {
  width: 550px;
  border: none;;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  height:200px;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.sibling {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height:200px;
}
.sibling.root:after {
  content: 'Sibling';
  color: green;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.float:after {
  content: 'floated Element';
  color: red;
}
.root {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"> 
</div>
<div class="sibling root">
 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not the best , but I tried to help the guy with a solution since nobody had one for him ?

Comment: Your answer doesn't show a solution that follow a shaped figure. Furthermore, the question lack a code sample, and because of that there is too many viable options how to solve it, hence the questioner need to provide more info.

Comment: @JimCiaston thanx for your time Jim, the issue with the red dots is that they are not on the same h. line.

Comment: No problem , Is there writing on red dots, or do you just want red dots ?

Comment: @JimCiaston Dots have onclick ovent that show the line and the text which have to be linedup with the dot, very similar to the image postaed image in the original post.